# 155. Min stack (leetcode problem) wrong returning value

Tags: javascript

I need some help with this. I think I implement getMin correctly (the problem is asking constant
time) but its returning -2 not -3 for the second call. I try to console.log what values are in the array but value looked okay. Thank you guys! [this is my output for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWBLT.png)

```js
var MinStack = function() {
    this.arr = [];
    this.length = 0;
    this.min = Infinity;
};

/** 
 * @param {number} x
 * @return {void}
 */
MinStack.prototype.push = function(x) {
    this.arr[this.length] = x;
    this.length++;
    if (x < this.min) {
        this.min = x;
    }
    console.log(this.min)
};

/**
 * @return {void}
 */
MinStack.prototype.pop = function() {
    if (this.length < 0) return;
    const newArr = [];
    
    for (let i=0; i<this.length-1; i++) {
        newArr.push(this.arr[i])
    }
    return
};

/**
 * @return {number}
 */
MinStack.prototype.top = function() {
    let topNum = -Infinity;
    
    for (let i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
        if (this.arr[i] > topNum) {
            topNum = this.arr[i]
        }
    }
    return topNum;
};

/**
 * @return {number}
 */
MinStack.prototype.getMin = function() {
    if (this.min === Infinity) return;
    return this.min
};

const minStack = new MinStack();
minStack.push(-2);
minStack.push(0);
minStack.push(-3);
minStack.getMin(); // return -3
minStack.pop();
minStack.top();    // return 0
minStack.getMin(); // return -2
```

Comment: what do you mean by that? I thought I did add code to the snippet?

Comment: Running the snippet doesn't produce anything. We don't know what the expected input is. We also don't know what the problem statement is, so it's a bit hard to figure out what's wrong when we don't know what should be happening.

Comment: im not sure how to add them. Its not letting me add method call

Comment: I add what im trying to add as comment but its not letting me add them

Comment: Rather `pop` is problematic, as it doesn't do anything, and returns `undefined`. See [at jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2y90kren/), the code doesn't behave like you've described. Notice, that all the logs in your example are coming from `push`, and they also are correct.

Comment: Also, if `pop` is meant to do the same as `Array.pop` (remove the last member from an array), and it would work properly, then `-2` would be correct, as `-3` is the last member in that array, and when removed, `-2` should be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the updated snippet here for your problem. I added comments to the places that you may have questions about.

Several key points:

1. Instead of only using `this.min` for minimal values, we should use a stack. Example: for array `[1,2,3]`, the minimum value is 3, but after a `pop` it should be 2. If you go through the array to find the minimum value again, it would be too slow and unnecessary.
2. Array has its own [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) methods; you don't need to implement them on your own.
3. We should use `<=` instead of `<` when comparing values, as the array is not all unique values. Example: `[3,2,2]`, after a `pop` the minimal value is still 2. If you use `<` here, it would be wrong.
4. [LeetCode discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/min-stack/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_votes&query=) and [some Youtube solution video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YiqLMmdBJFk) could be helpful resources.

My updated version of your code:

```js
var MinStack = function () {
  this.arr = [];
  // this.length = 0; // unnecessary
  // this.min = Infinity; // unnecessary, we can use minStack to maintain the minimal value
  this.minStack = []; // should maintain a stack
};

/**
 * @param {number} x
 * @return {void}
 */
MinStack.prototype.push = function (x) {
  // this.arr[this.length] = x;
  // this.length++;
  this.arr.push(x);
  if (
    this.minStack.length === 0 ||
    x <= this.minStack[this.minStack.length - 1]
  ) {
    // we should use <= here, as duplicate values are possible
    this.minStack.push(x);
  }
  // console.log(this.min);
};

/**
 * @return {void}
 */
MinStack.prototype.pop = function () {
  // if (this.length < 0) return; // unnecessary to maintain length
  if (!this.arr) return;
  const pop = this.arr.pop(); // use .pop()
  if (pop === this.minStack[this.minStack.length - 1]) {
    // update minimal value, if poped value is also minimal value
    this.minStack.pop();
  }
  // const newArr = [];

  // for (let i = 0; i < this.length - 1; i++) {
  //   newArr.push(this.arr[i]);
  // }
  // return;
};

/**
 * @return {number}
 */
MinStack.prototype.top = function () {
  // let topNum = -Infinity;

  // for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
  //   if (this.arr[i] > topNum) {
  //     topNum = this.arr[i];
  //   }
  // }
  // return topNum;

  // can just easily return the last item in this.arr
  return this.arr[this.arr.length - 1];
};

/**
 * @return {number}
 */
MinStack.prototype.getMin = function () {
  // if (this.min === Infinity) return;
  // return this.min;
  if (!this.minStack) return;
  // the last item in this.minStack is the minimal value
  return this.minStack[this.minStack.length - 1];
};

const minStack = new MinStack();
minStack.push(-2);
minStack.push(0);
minStack.push(-3);
const v1 = minStack.getMin(); // return -3
minStack.pop();
const v3 = minStack.top(); // return 0
const v4 = minStack.getMin(); // return -2

console.log([v1, v3, v4]);
console.log(JSON.stringify([v1, v3, v4]) === JSON.stringify([-3, 0, -2]));
```

updated code is working correctly now, as you can see `true` in the last line being printed.